# DataGridView update источника данных

Tags: c#, update, datagridview

Дано: DataGridView привязана к BindingSource, BindingSource привязан к таблице из DataSet, DataSet получает данные из TableAdapter.

У DGV на ивент CellEndEdit "вешаем": "Tab1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet1);"
т.е. после того как редактирование ячейки закончено мы обновляем данные в БД. Но это работает только в том случае если мы изменили значение в ячейке и щелкнули на другую ячейку.Если же после изменения значения нажать Enter то данные в БД не обновятся. Даже если если создать отдельную кнопку с "Tab1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet1);" ничего не произойдет. Возможно DGV не понимает что данные в нем были изменены и не передает данные в Dataset следовательно и обновление не проходит. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть.

**Form1.cs**

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.TAB1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tAB1TableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.TAB1);

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        tAB1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet1);
    }
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
private void InitializeComponent(){
...
...
...
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.dataSet1 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.DataSet1();
        this.tAB1BindingSource = new    System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        this.tAB1TableAdapter = new WindowsFormsApplication1.DataSet1TableAdapters.TAB1TableAdapter();

        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.cLDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.tAB1BindingSource;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 62);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(478, 317);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
        // 
        // dataSet1
        // 
        this.dataSet1.DataSetName = "DataSet1";
        this.dataSet1.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
        // 
        // tAB1BindingSource
        // 
        this.tAB1BindingSource.DataMember = "TAB1";
        this.tAB1BindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1;
        // 
        // tAB1TableAdapter
        // 
        this.tAB1TableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: Приведите код - по другому внятного ответа не получите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение найдено.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    tAB1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, событие `CellEndEdit` возникает только после потери фокуса ячейкой. Вам нужно дополнительно обрабатывать событие [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: к несчастью дело не в событие,  я пробовал принудительно вызывать  _tAB1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet1);_ использовав кнопку, данные в БД не получают измененных значений. Все работает отлично если после редактирования ячейки щелкнуть на другую ячейку. Но если использовать клавишу Enter или щелкнуть на любой другой элемент, и так же вызывать _tAB1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet1); то ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Halva - Не верю! (с) Может у вас обработчик клика не присоединен к кнопке? Мне кажется, причина банальная - где-то забыт вызов чего-то.